# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied

Tags: jquery

I am using **jQuery AJAX** to call a **webservice** method from ASP.Net using JavaScript. When I use the web service in local system it works good but when I upload the same webservice to an IIS Server it  shows error called  **'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied'**. Give me a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you give more information?